# How to change a Callback signature that also accepts class methods and free functions?

Tags: c++

I have a Callback which looks like this:

```cpp
typedef void(*Callback)(EventInfo event_info);
```

This can be used with free functions, but when I try to use class methods it fails with the error :

```cpp
Error   C2276   '&': illegal operation on bound member function expression
```

How should I go about this and make it so that it also accepts a class method just like a free function. That is I could simply do :

```cpp
struct MyClass
{
   void some_methods(EventInfo info)
   {
      sth;
   }
}

void some_functions(EventInfo info)
{
   sth;
}
int main()
{
   MyClass obj;

   myobj.AddOnSthChanged(obj.somemethods);
   myobj.AddOnSthChanged(some_functions);
...
```

Comment: std::function and std::bind are for these purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointers on function are limited to .. pointers on function.

To allow any callable, you have to use template or type erasure as `std::function`:

```
using Callback = std::function<void(EventInfo)>;

struct MyClass
{
     Callback callback;
};


struct A
{
    void foo(EventInfo) {}
};

void bar(EventInfo) {}

int main()
{
    EventInfo event;
    MyClass c1{bar};
    c1.callback(event); // bar(event);

    A a;
    MyClass c2{ [&a](EventInfo event){ a.foo(event); }};
    c1.callback(event); // a.foo(event);
}
```